# How to get model value to controller?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3.1 .

I want to pass posted data through model, but to pass login i need to get model value to controller ?

How to get model value to controller?

**Controller**

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model("user_login");
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $post = $this->input->post("post", true);

        if ($this->user_login->check($post)) {
            if ($this->user_login->logins == "pass") {  
                echo "valid";
            } else {
                echo "Invalid";
            }
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class User_Login extends CI_Model 
{
    var $logins=false;

    public function check($post) 
    {
        $results = $this->db->where('username', $post)
                            ->get('users');

        if($results->num_rows() > 0){
            $this->logins = "pass";
        } else {
            $this->logins = "fail";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to use [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Comment: I know that but is it possible to get value?

Comment: How old is your PHP OOP? `var`??? Not sure if it will make a difference but you might try `public $logins=false;`

Comment: Sorry i don't understand .

Comment: The `var` keyword has long since been deprecated. You should use one of `public`, `protected`, or `private` to declare a class member variable. In this case, `public` would help you - although there are a number of reasons why it would be better to use other methods of getting member variables.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) At first, if you want to use any public variable, no need to use var with it. Just write `$logins=false;`

2) Next you should something from your model for checking this type of thing. Like `return "pass"` or `return "fail"`

3) After that when you check it from controller, you can keep this return data to a variable like this `$return_value = $this->user_login->check($post)`. At last, it can be like below code -

```
 if ($return_value) {
    if ($return_value == "pass") {   
    echo "valid";
   } else {
    echo "Invalid";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Controller

```
class Login extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("user_login");
    }

    public function index()
    {

       $post = $this->input->post("post", true);

       if ($this->user_login->check($post)==true) {
          echo "valid";
       }
       else{
          echo "invalid";
       }
   }
} 
?>
```

modal

```
 <?php

 class User_Login extends CI_Model 
 {
    var $logins=false;

    public function check($post) 
    {
       $results = $this->db->where('username', $post)
                        ->get('users');

       if($results->num_rows() > 0){
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
   }
 }
?>
```